# Re-format an array of objects in Javascript in custom array format by property id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having trouble reformatting an Object array in Javascript. I have an array that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "deviceid": 42,
    "x": "2022-03-26T00:00:18",
    "y": 17.8,
  },
  {
    "deviceid": 42,
    "x": "2022-03-26T00:01:18",
    "y": 17.8,
  },
  {
    "deviceid": 43,
    "x": "2022-03-26T00:02:18",
    "y": 17.8,
  {
    "deviceid": 43,
    "x": "2022-03-26T00:02:18",
    "y": 17.8,
  }]
```

I want to re-shape it so the new form will be one record per device id and all x and y values in the same row.

```
[
  {
    "deviceid": 42,
    "x": ["2022-03-26T00:00:18","2022-03-27T00:00:18"],
    "y": [17.8, 15.6],
  },
  {
    "deviceid": 43,
    "x": ["2022-03-26T00:01:18","2022-03-27T00:00:18"],
    "y": [17.8, 19.1],
  }]
```

How can I make this happen?

Comment: It's syntactically wrong, go to https://jshint.com/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to do the reduction of your values using a JavaScript object. After the reduction get the values of the object using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

```js
const data = [
  {
    deviceid: 42,
    x: "2022-03-26T00:00:18",
    y: 17.8,
  },
  {
    deviceid: 42,
    x: "2022-03-26T00:01:18",
    y: 15.6,
  },
  {
    deviceid: 43,
    x: "2022-03-26T00:02:18",
    y: 17.8,
  },
  {
    deviceid: 43,
    x: "2022-03-26T00:02:18",
    y: 19.1,
  },
];

const result = data.reduce((devices, device) => {
  // check if we have encountered this decive before using the deviceId
  if (!devices.hasOwnProperty(device.deviceid)) {
    // we have not: create an key-value pair using device ID as key and device info as value
    // use an array for x and y
    devices[device.deviceid] = {
      deviceId: device.deviceid,
      x: [device.x],
      y: [device.y],
    };
  } else {
    // we have seen this device before 
    // get the device value using the key (deviceId) and push new x and y values to it
    const curDev = devices[device.deviceid];
    curDev.x.push(device.x);
    curDev.y.push(device.y);
  }
  // return JS object of devices for next iteration/ result
  return devices;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

> Please note: I think the input you have provided in your question contains some errors probably from copy/ pasting as the expected output contains values that are not in the input at all. I have changed values of `y` in the input to show you that output is actually what you expect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It works as intended. You are also right about the input errors. It was just for the example purposes and are wrong from copy / pasting.